# Arduino LED actuator

Tags: arduino, books

I bought the Arduino starter kit and in the project book they say that the pin 13 led is an actuator. I thought actuators were a type of motor.

It says:

> "Pin 13 LED. The only actuator build-in to your Arduino Uno. Besides being a handy target for your first blink sketch, this LED is very useful for debugging."

Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! It's not clear what you are asking, can you try to be more specific? Are you asking why there is only one actuator? Why it is called an actuator? Why they say it is useful for debugging? Why it is a handy target for your first sketch?

Comment: Joe Hass, my question was why the arduino project book would refer the LED as an actuator. I always thought actuators meant a type of motor. But in a later reference in the book they said that "things that convert electrical energy into other forms of energy are sometimes called actuators" which i found a bit odd. Ive never heard someone call a LED an actuator. So im wondering what you think.

Comment: I think the word they were looking for is "transducer".

Comment: I think that the correct answer is the simplest: there was a mistake in the book. @Ignacio is right: they were trying to say "transducer"

Comment: if you would organise all electronic components into categories of sensors and actuators, LED would probably go into actuators, isn't it or which category would you add for it ?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "actuator" is a mis-translation?  I would call the LED an indicator.

When debugging a program on a microcontroller, it is often handy to have a LED that know will work to use as an indicator that the program has reached a certain place, or attempted to do some action. Eg: set the LED on when a motor should start, and off when it stops - if the LED works, but the motor doesn't, you might start looking at the wiring for a problem...

Comment: I just read this a few pages later.
"Things that convert electrical energy into other forms of energy are sometimes called actuactors"
I guess thats why they called the led an actuactor? Led transform electrical energy to light?
Sound wierd to me

Comment: @TResell: It's certainly an unusual use of the word *actuator*. Mostly the word suggests a motor that moves or controls some mechanical system.

Comment: @TResell , I believe that instead of driving an actuator, which could run in to end stops and damage it's self or cause an overload, you can indicate the drive signal is active with an LED. This is very useful to do before connecting the real thing and for debugging the code (It's common to get the logic reversed in drive circuits and cause other problems like runaway conditions)

Comment: @TResell it's an error. An actuator, by all common definition, requires mechanical movement or force. An electromagnetic solenoid can be an actuator, but not an led.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the [Arduino UNO schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf)

The relevant part is

[image: arduino uno]

and it shows that there is indeed a led connected to pin 13